# New MongoId() solution during migration from PHP 5.5 to in PHP 7

Tags: php, mongodb, mongoid, pecl, php-mongodb

In PHP7 new MongoId() is not working and solution to get mongo id in php7 using below function `var_dump(new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId())`, but I am using this in multiple files almost more than 200 files so I don't want manually edit all these files.

So can anybody tell me is there any trick like using `__autolaod(),spl_autoload_register()` function so we can add some code and that will will automatically called for new `MongoId()` function and return the mongoID without an error.

I just need a smart solution without editing multiple files.